# Send php while loop variables to javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

My file.js is calling a php file to fetch from database and return an encoded JSON object so I can put it on a table. Here is the file.js -

```
url = "backend.php"
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {
        myJSONObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for ( i=0;i<myJSON.length;i++)
         {
          var x = document.getElementById("datatable").rows[i].cells;
          x[6].innerHTML =obj[i].age;
         }
     }
 }
```

And the backend.php file goes -

```
$sql_stmt= "SELECT * FROM TABLE ";
$result = odbc_exec($conn_id, $sql_stmt);
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
$age=$row['age'];
$ages[] = array('age'=> $age);
}
$myJSON = json_encode($ages);
echo $myJSON;
```

This works completely fine, but I have to wait for the PHP while loop to finish, which takes too long with large number of entries. I want to be able to return the JSON within the loop, not at the end.
Is there any way I can make the xmlhttp request and keep receiving JSON while the PHP while loop runs, not having to wait for it to finish and then send across all the rows together? Thanks

Comment: You must have to wait for all result, if you are having the huge data then do pagination ( send max and offset to mysql to get chunked data)

Comment: yes you can, 1. Prepare php page to return total rows
2.  access it using Javascript ajax
3. Prepare php page to return per row by id 
4 loop in javascript with rowID param and call 2nd php page

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use mysql limit

JS:

```
var hasData = true;
var loop = 0;

while(hasData){

url = "backend.php?page="+loop;
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {
    if(this.reponseText != ""){

        myJSONObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for ( i=0;i<myJSON.length;i++)
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("datatable").rows[i].cells;
            x[6].innerHTML =obj[i].age;
        }
    }else{
        hasData = false; //if no data retrieved
    }//end if

    }//end if
 }


loop++; //increment loop

}//end while
```

PHP:

```
$loop = $_GET['loop'];
if($loop != ""){
    $max_output = 10; //how many rows you want to display per query
    $starting_row = $max_output * $loop; 
    // LIMIT 0, 10 = if loop is 0
        // LIMIT 10, 10 = if loop is 1
    // LIMIT 20, 10 = if loop is 2

    $sql_stmt= "SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT {$starting_row}, {$max_output}";
    $result = odbc_exec($conn_id, $sql_stmt);
    if($result){
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
            $age=$row['age'];
            $ages[] = array('age'=> $age);
        }
        $myJSON = json_encode($ages);
        echo $myJSON;
    }else{
        exit; //make sure nothing is echoed/print
    }
}

    {
        myJSONObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for ( i=0;i<myJSON.length;i++)
         {
          var x = document.getElementById("datatable").rows[i].cells;
          x[6].innerHTML =obj[i].age;
         }
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is exactly what I thought of and am using right now but requirement documents disallow me from making multiple queries.  
With one fetch of all the data together( which is pretty quick) I need to send back JSON one row at a time within the loop. That's the only way I think would be fast enough.
I'm assuming that doesn't exist though so I'll accept your answer if there's nothing else soon

Comment: Welcome. How about populate your data into a file, mydata.json. Maybe you can use cron or daemon that runs your populate json script every 5 minutes or so. Though this will be troublesome if you have to implement it to all your tables.